# Animation and UILabel change text

Tags: objective-c, animation, uilabel, nstimer

I have an UIImageView and an UILabel in a view of my storyboard. I created 2 corresponding IBOutlet and an NSTimer in the controller.

Each 0.01 seconds, the timer call the following method which moves the image:

```
-(void) update{

    CGRect rect = myImageOutlet.frame;
    rect.origin.x += 1;
    myImageOutlet.frame = rect;
}
```

It works well. Now I would also like to change the text of the label in this method in order to display the current elapsed time (to do so I initialize an NSDate in the viewDidLoad and I use on it the method timeIntervalSinceNow)

Now the text of the label changes correctly but the image stays at it's original place.

I found a workaround by adding **programmatically** to my controller a subview and putting the label in this subview.

What is strange is that I tried to do the same by adding an UIView and an UILabel through the object library in the storyboard (and not programmatically), and it does not work.

Do you have any idea why ?
(and if you also know why the image is not moving if I change the label text I am interested)

Comment: It's because of auto layout. When you set the frame of a view that's using auto layout, it will move back to the position determined by its constraints when the view needs to be redrawn (like when your label gets updated).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I understand well when updating the label text the whole view will be redrawn. Do you know why it does not happen when I add the subview programmatically? (I guess in that case only the subview is redrawn. I would like to do the same through the storyboard if possible)

Comment: No, it doesn't have to do with what is redrawn. When you add the view programmatically, it isn't using auto layout unless you added layout constraints yourself. In the scoreboard, if auto layout is turned on (which it is by default), the views will have layout constraints added to them. Even if you don't add them yourself, the system adds them for you.

Comment: Ok thanks so I will just add them programmatically (but now I understand why).